# How to create an array in Java with multiple data types to be used in another class

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

So I'm new to Java and learning whilst I program. I have a class called Compiler which has a number of variables of different data types. I currently have them as separate variables but ideally they need to be in an array list which I can then use in another class called Broker.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Compiler{
        public static String item="top";
        public static Integer minprice=8;
        public static Integer maxprice=15;
        public static Integer qty=1;
```

This is the start of my code and I've been trying to make an array I can use in my Broker class but I'm struggling, can anyone help?

Comment: In your Broker class you can create an ArrayList of Compiler instances (remove static from the declarations though - it has specific semantics that you don't want in this case - though without seeing more code it is hard to tell). Eg:       List<Compiler> compilers = new ArrayList<Compiler>();    compilers.add(new Compiler()); ...

Comment: It's not clear as to how the variables are stored. Should it be multiple arrays in one object or one array of multiple objects?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - your question is to vauge to be ansered precisely. Maybe you explain the purpose of your program and the reason why you think you need this array...

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store multiple `Compiler` objects then you can use `ArrayList<Compiler>` (as mentioned by James Fry in the comments) like so:

```
public class Compiler {
    public String item="top";
    public Integer minprice=8;
    public Integer maxprice=15;
    public Integer qty=1;
}

public class Broker {
    // If you are using Java SE 7,          you can omit the type here
    ArrayList<Compiler> arr = new ArrayList<Compiler>();
}
```

To improve design, you can set the access modifier to `private` and create [getter and setter functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html)

You can add and remove elements by using the [add(T) and remove(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) methods.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still really new, how do I add the items to the array list then?

Comment: You can omit the type (use diamond syntax) since Java 7.

Comment: @DavidConrad oh thanks! :)

Comment: @Olivia see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Object[]` array where you can store any value:

```
Object[] array = new Object[]{"top", 8, 15, 1};
```

However, normally, it is better to define a class where such values are assigned to fields (often accessed by `get...`/`set...` methods), each with a well-defined type and meaning.

Also, `static` denotes that fields are stored in the class and they will have the same value in each `Compiler` object, which is likely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix different types in a single ArrayList. If your goal is to pass those four variables to Broker and then use the String for one thing, the first int for something else, etc. just make the fields non-static and construct a Compiler object, then pass the object to Broker and retrieve the variables from there.